# Segmentation Fault With Array object when calling constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, object, segmentation-fault

**This is the base class**

```
class Product{

    protected:
        
        string model;
        double price;
        int qty;
        
    public:
        
        Product() { // default constructor
            model = "";
            price = 0.00;
            qty = 0;
        }
        
        //setter method:
        void setProduct(string m, double p, int q){ // set the values of Product (model, price, and quantity)
            model = m;
            price = p;
            qty = q;
        }
        
        //getter method:
        string getProduct(){ // get the product by returning the string model (unique data in the list)
            return model;
        }
        
        int countLength(); // functino to count the number of products in a list
        int seqSearch(string item, int length); // sequential search to search thru the list
        void add();
        void insertAt(int length, string newModel, double newPrice, int newQty); // add() and insertAt method used to insert a product into a list
        void del(); 
        void removeAt(int loc, int length); // del() and removeAt() methods is used to remove a product from a list
        void view(); // display all info in a list
        void select(); // method to select a product/item in a list
        void view(int location); // view a selected product in a list... overloading the view() method
        
        ~Product(){ // destructor
            delete [] this;
        }
};
```

**This is the derived classes**

```
class Computer: public Product{
    
    public:
        
        //constructors
        Computer(){} // default constructor
        Computer(string m, double p, int q); // overloading constructor for preset data
                
        void view();
        
        ~Computer(){ // destructor
            delete [] this;
        }
 };

class Accessory: public Product{
    
    public:
        
        //constructoirs
        Accessory(){} // default constructor
        Accessory(string m, double p, int q);
        
        void view();
        
        ~Accessory(){ // destructor
            delete [] this;
        }
};

class Printer: public Product{
    
    public:
        
        //constructors
        Printer(){} // default constructor
        Printer(string m, double p, int q);
        
        void view();
        
        ~Printer(){ // destructor
            delete [] this;
        }
};

class Other: public Product{
    
    public:
        
        //constructors
        Other(){} // default constructor
        Other(string m, double p, int q);
        
        void view();
        
        ~Other(){ //destructor
            delete [] this;
        }
};
```

**Here is the overloaded constructors of derived classes**

```
Computer::Computer(string m, double p, int q){
    this->setProduct(m, p, q);
}

Accessory::Accessory(string m, double p, int q){
    this->setProduct(m, p, q);
}

Printer::Printer(string m, double p, int q){
    this->setProduct(m, p, q);
}

Other::Other(string m, double p, int q){
    this->setProduct(m, p, q);
}
```

**This is the objects declarations**

```
Computer *Computers = new Computer[maxSize];
Accessory *Accessories = new Accessory[maxSize];
Printer *Printers = new Printer[maxSize];
Other *Others = new Other[maxSize];
```

**The problem is when I call the Object[i] = Class(string, double, int) and it is a segmentation fault I guess**

```
void presetData(){
    Computers[0] = Computer("C1C1C1", 2000.00, 6);
    Computers[1] = Computer("C2C2C2", 2500.00, 2);
    Accessories[0] = Accessory("A1A1A1", 200.00, 6);
    Printers[0] = Printer("P1P1P1", 300.00, 4);
    Others[0] = Other("O1O1O1", 100.00, 1);
}
```

**Why can't I access the Object[i] and it gives segmentation fault?**

Comment: Why do you `delete [] this;` in the destructors?

Comment: Why line seg faults and where are the object declarations?

Comment: Remove the `delete [] this` from your destuctors. The fact you've got this in your code suggests you don't understand how destructors work...

Comment: You will very likely encounter the same issue if you just create a single object; `Computer("C1C1C1", 2000.00, 6);`

Answer (score 2):

When the temporary object `Computer("C1C1C1", 2000.00, 6)` is destroyed, it does `delete [] this;`, but `this` does not point to the first element of an array created with `new`.
This has undefined behaviour, and you're lucky it crashes.
To make it even worse, it does this *twice* - once in `Product::~Product` and once in `Computer::~Computer`.

Remove all the lines that say `delete [] this;` - this thing does not belong in a destructor, and you have never seen any example that does it.
(Unless it was an example of things that you shouldn't do.)

Then read some more about constructors and destructors, and how to work with dynamic allocation,  in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful the fact that you mentioned that the delete [] this invoked twice(once in the base class and once in that class itself). I have tried to remove all the lines that say delete [] this; before, except in the parent class and get the same error. And now I get that delete this should not be used in the destructor.